# How to control the format of float numbers in gawk?

Tags: awk

The following two runs are different. How to make the first run the same as the second run (I still want `print` without any explicit arguments)? Is there a way to control the number of digits in `$1 = 1/3`?

```
$ gawk -v OFMT='%.20g' -e 'BEGIN { $1 = 1/3; print }'
0.333333
$ gawk -v OFMT='%.20g' -e 'BEGIN { print 1/3}'
0.33333333333333331483
```

EDIT: The following comparison is also unexpected. Ideally, if there is just one field, `print $1` and `print` should be just the same. I think it could be considered as a bug?

```
$ gawk -v OFMT='%.20g' -e 'BEGIN { $1 = 1/3; print $1}'
0.33333333333333331483
$ gawk -v OFMT='%.20g' -e 'BEGIN { $1 = 1/3; print}'
0.333333
```

Comment: I'm guessing because you are printing the whole line by default with `print` that it's causing it to treat your output as a string(?????? totally guessing here). I say this because: `gawk -v OFMT='%.20g' -e 'BEGIN { $1 = 1/3; print $1}'` works as intended.

Comment: This is just an example. In practice, I may need to print all the fields. So I can not just specify some particular fields.

Comment: Oh! And for fun... this `gawk 'BEGIN { $1 = 1/3; printf "%.20g\n", $0 }'` gives a different answer then `gawk 'BEGIN { $1 = 1/3; printf "%.20g\n", $1 }'` where the `.333333` is all float-rounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a subtlety here. There are two variables, `OFMT` and `CONVFMT`. The variable `OFMT` is used to control how numbers are converted to strings in the `print` statement while the variable `CONVFMT` is used to define how numbers are converted to strings in general (outside of the `print` statement):

> Prior to the POSIX standard, awk used the value of `OFMT` for converting numbers to strings. `OFMT` specifies the output format to use when printing numbers with `print`. `CONVFMT` was introduced in order to separate the semantics of conversion from the semantics of printing. Both `CONVFMT` and `OFMT` have the same default value: `"%.6g"`. In the vast majority of cases, old awk programs do not change their behaviour.
>
> **<sub>source: [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html)</sub>**

More detailed information about this reasoning can be found in the [secion **rationale** of the awk POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).

**numeric value in print statement:**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print 1/3}' 
0.333333
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFMT="%.20g"; print 1/3 }'
0.33333333333333331483
$ awk 'BEGIN{CONVFMT="%.20g"; print 1/3 }'
0.333333
```

**variable with a numeric value in print statement:**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{a=1/3; print a}'
0.333333
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFMT="%.20g"; a=1/3; print a }'
0.33333333333333331483
$ awk 'BEGIN{CONVFMT="%.20g"; a=1/3; print a }'
0.333333
```

**variable with a numeric value converted to string in print statement:**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{a=1/3; a=a""; print a}'
0.333333
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFMT="%.20g"; a=1/3; a=a""; print a }'
0.333333
$ awk 'BEGIN{CONVFMT="%.20g"; a=1/3; a=a""; print a }'
0.33333333333333331483
```

Comment: So the conclusion to make the behavior consistent. I should set both OFMT and CONVFMT to the same value?

Comment: Whoa I completely forgot about CONVFMT

Comment: Imagine you would only have `OFMT` and you have something like : `{a[1.5]="X"; OFMT="%.20g"; print a[1.5]}`. This would return nothing as the original key of 1.5 is converted with `%.6g` which was changed afterwards. so the key would never be found. Hence the usage of `CONVFMT`. This resolves this problem, unless you change it again mid-run. So changing `OFMT` does not break any other numeric-string comparisons mid-run.

Comment: @user1424739 So yes, to be safe, you can change both `OFMT` and `CONVFMT` at the same time, but you should not change `CONVFMT` anymore afterwards, you might break your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if its a bug, but try to set a variable and not first field

```
gawk -v OFMT='%.20g' -e 'BEGIN { a = 1/3; print a}'
0.33333333333333331483
```

Comment: That is not the point. I still want to just use `print` without any explicit argument.

Comment: @user1424739 Your question `How to control the format of float numbers in gawk?` printf can be used instead of OFMT

Comment: `printf` requires knowing NF. With `print`, I don't need to know NF.

Comment: @user1424739 Updated my answer